# Getting all records in many-to-many relationship even if the relationship is missing

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `user` table, `group` table, and `user_group` table for many to many.

I am confused on how I can get the list of all users belonging to a specific group and if the user does not belong to the current group, I still want his record listed with the group field set to **NULL**.

Comment: sample data, expected output and your attempt would be helpful.

Comment: Sounds like it needs to be treated similarly to a full outer join, since it is kind of an aggregation of one; so you'll need to query for the "left" (groups and their users) and "right"(groupless users) halves separately and UNION them. _This assumes you want to include userless groups in your results._

Comment: Out of topic, but the commissioner of NBA knows SQL.

Comment: @LKTN.25 I have always wondered if that's an honour for SQL or me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do:

```
select u.*, ug.group_id
from users u left join
     user_group ug
     on ug.user_id = u.user_id and ug.group_id = <the group>;
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about including a group without users, this should work; all groupless users should be collected together under the NULL group_id's userIDs.

```
SELECT g.group_id, GROUP_CONCAT(u.user_id) AS userIDs
FROM `users` AS u
LEFT JOIN `user_group` AS ug ON u.user_id = ug.user_id
LEFT JOIN `group` AS g ON ug.group_id = g.group_id
GROUP BY g.group_id
;
```